# Which is correct "why is" or just "why" in this example?

Tags: word-order, questions, do-support

> Why this expression is evaluating to 110?

or

> Why is this expression is evaluating to 110?

Which is correct? If the second one, why in some places do we see example one?

Comment: Neither. Correct is: "why is this expression evaluating to 110?"

Comment: Can you provide an actual example for your first option?  'Why' always takes a verb.

Comment: the question is, we have to use "is" after the why ?

Comment: But we often see example #1 in places where people are speaking English as a second language.

Comment: Closely related: [No inversion in questions in headlines and titles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229650/no-inversion-in-questions-in-headlines-and-titlesstions-in-headlines-and-titles). You need to tell us where you saw the No. 1 sentence.

Comment: Example 1 is fine as a title or header before an explanation, but not as a question.

Comment: Oh wait. You can use #1 in sentences that are longer. For instance, "This proof shows why this expression is evaluating to 110." Maybe someone whould post an answer about this.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Ty (fixed). Re "credible alternatives", I think *Why **does** this expression **evaluate** to 110?* is probably the most likely form.

Comment: The use of "is evaluating" suggests a foreign speaker of English, possibly copying their own language's constructions.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't know why "is evaluating" would sound more foreign to a native ear than "does evaluate", but that could be just me. (I'm not a native speaker either.)

Comment: :D , I wanna ask my question again which is correct “why is” or just “why” in this example? just please tell me about why or why is

Comment: @MrLister: because "evaluate" (in this sense) is eternal, so the progressive form is very odd: it implies that at this moment it evaluates to 110, but later it might have a different value. And actually, now I think about it, even if that were the case, I would still say "This expression currently evaluates to 110". I can't imagine using "is evaluating" ever in this sense. I have an impression that the progressive is used more in Indian English, though, so if this is from India it might be OK.

Comment: @Sam, I'm sorry, but you're asking the wrong question. Neither of your examples is grammatical, so the answer to your specific question is "neither". The more useful information is what various people have given you:: in a "why" question, there must be a verb (nearly always an auxiliary such as 'is' or 'does') , and  the verb must come before the subject, so usually straight after the 'why'

Comment: @ColinFine, Thank you , I'm rookie to be honest, I'm looking for a teacher for a long time or someone that I can to talk to him about learning English. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, as standalone sentences, the question form is

> Why *is* this expression evaluating to 110?

or

> Why *does* this expression evaluate to 110?

*Why* usually takes a verb right after it in a question.

The answer form is

> Q: *What is the value of the expression?*
>   A: This expression **is** evaluating to 110.

This answer might used if the person is looking at the instrument while it is measuring. similar to

> The temperature is *hovering* around 80 degrees.

Comment: So shall we say the my first example, is informal ? or it's completely wrong? I ask because I see "why" without "is" in several texts.

Comment: It's understandable, but it's not correct. BTW, in txts, lots of fny thgs hppn due 2 the nature of txting.